# What is combinatorially possible, for a singular minimal surface in $\mathbf{R}^3$?

Tags: minimal-surfaces

A cubic planar graph gives a cell decomposition of a two-sphere, whose dual complex is a triangulation.  If I understand Plateau's laws [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_laws), a soap film gives a cell decomposition whose dual complex is a triangulation of a three-sphere.  Are there any combinatorial restrictions on the triangulations that can appear, as dual to a genuine soap film in $\mathbf{R}^3$?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you allowing the faces and regions of the soap bubbles to be non-simply connected? For example there are (unstable) toroidal double bubbles satisfying Plateau's laws. One can form a dual complex abstractly, but it might not be a triangulation of S^3 (for example, there may be no vertices).
http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Images/double/

Comment: Hi Ian.  I'd be just as interested to find out there are combinatorial restrictions on foam with nonsimply-connected bubbles.  But the actual question that came up for me is even more restricted: if you draw a cubic planar graph on the boundary of a ball, what kind of minimal surfaces, with Plateau singularities and without interior regions, can you fill inside?